# .java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details Not sure which part of code

Tags: java

I'm new in the JAVA realm, I wrote a code for my assignment and it works fine when I compile it using Netbeans. When I compile my .java file via cmd, I get the error mentioned above. I would had been helpful if it could identify which line produced an unsafe operation, but for the life of me I don't know which part the source the compiler was referring to.

Code here: http://pastebin.com/nmTqghDi

cmd line used: javac Barcenas_PA.java

Comment: You won't, until you do what it says to do.

Comment: recompile it using the flag `-Xlint:unchecked`. It will tell you exactly where you are going wrong like `javac classname -Xlint:unchecked`.

Comment: Use Eclipse. It will warn you when you mess things up. Netbeans do this to, you have to configure it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have initialised your array lists to raw types on line

```
79
100
207
228
275
282
353
401
413
426
439 and 
452
```

This operation is unsafe coz you never know what type of objects your data structure may store.

Now since `java.util.ArrayList` is a generic class, you must initialise it as

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Or as of Java 7 and later

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();  // Empty angular brackets to simplify initialisation.
```

If you still get suck warnings, compile it like this:

```
javac course_214_ma/Barcenas_PA.java -Xlint:unchecked
```

Comment: you must have taken out some lines... The first problem is on line 86... I was doing that list on eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Check line 86.  ArrayList instantiations must have the generic tag as well.
E.g.

```
ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>
```

Answer (score 1):

This

```
ArrayList<String> dataRow = new ArrayList();
```

is a [raw-type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html), change it to

```
ArrayList<String> dataRow = new ArrayList<>();
```

You have a lot of raw types. Then you never use `counter`. Either comment it out, or print it, or put it in an `if`. Finally, you can ignore the warnings about not closing `Scanner`. Because you wrap `System.in` closing those `Scanner`(s) would be a bad idea.